# Powershell - ExecuteNonQuery (Transact-SQL) error message

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql, error-handling

I have a powershell script that runs SQL scripts in a SQL Server database using a new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection like this:

```
$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
```

And to run the script I use the ExecuteNonQuery method:

```
$conn.ExecuteNonQuery($ScriptToRun);
```

The script might fail. When this happens, I need the powershell script to print the detailed exception message, but it always print the same generic message: '**Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "1" argument(s): "An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch."**'

The error handling is made like this:

```
Catch
    {
        Write-Output $_.Exception.Message

        $conn.RollBackTransaction()
        throw $_.Exception

    }
```

Is there any way that I can print the specific Transact-SQL error that was thrown?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll want to inspect `$_.Exception.InnerException` inside the `catch` block, it should hold the underlying `SqlException` instance(s)

Comment: So like `Write-Output $_.Exception.InnerException.Message` ?

Comment: Or `Write-Host` or `Write-ToCustomLogFile`, depends how and where you want to consume this information :)